# How to return sum of n highest values in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Dice = () => {
    const [dice, setDice] = useState([1, 1, 2, 2]);

    function rollDice() {
        return Array.from({length: 4}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    }


    const handleClick = () => {
        setDice(rollDice());
    }

    const rolls = dice.map(die => <span> {die} </span> );

    const stat = dice.splice(Math.min(...dice)).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Roll for stats</button>

            <div>
                Your rolls are: {rolls}
            </div>
            
            <div>
                Your stat is: {stat}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Dice;

if (document.getElementById('dice')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Dice />, document.getElementById('dice'));
}
```

So I'm making online DnD and I'm testing out the dice rolls for stats, first few iterations went fine and then it returned the sum of the wrong numbers, it "randomly" removes the numbers I need and returns the wrong sum. I am doing this after being away from the code world for awhile so I'm sorry if it's something dumb but i really can't figure out what's the issue.

Comment: Never use `splice` in react like this. It modifies do original array. Better use `[...dice].splice`

Comment: Can you share with us your current output and the expected output? It would be great if you share some codesandbox link of output images.

Comment: I will be testing this stuff after i get back from work, but until then i'm sorry i can't help you help me, thank you for the comments and answers so far, looking foward to solving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce for this

```js
function sumOfNHighestValues(arr: number[], n: number): number {
  const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a); // sort the array in descending order
  const slicedArr = sortedArr.slice(0, n); // slice the first n elements
  const sum = slicedArr.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0); // sum the sliced elements
  return sum;
}

// example usage
const arr = [5, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4];
const n = 3;
const result = sumOfNHighestValues(arr, n);
console.log(result); // output: 21 (sum of 9, 8, and 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try es6 syntax, extension operator(...)

```
var arr = [22,13,6,55,30];
console.log(Math.max(...arr)); // 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, changing stat to a function and running the splice method on a copy of the dice array:

```
const stat = () => {
    let smallestRoll = Math.min(...dice)
    let indexOfSmallest = dice.indexOf(smallestRoll)
    let diceCopy = [...dice]

    diceCopy.splice(indexOfSmallest, 1)

    let sum = diceCopy.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    return sum;
}
```

and returning it as a function:

```
return (
    <>
        <div>
            Your stat is: {stat()}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

Thank you for all your help!